# Scala reply: load or run code from a URL

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

The scala REPL allows pre-loading of code with the syntax `scala -i <script.scala>` How is it possible to pre-load or execute code from a remote location such as https://gist.github.com/hanxue/8423482/raw/a525ae8a144d83195de72d402afb0fdc155cadf9/ConsoleColorise.scala ?

Are there options or plugins that allows

`scala -i http://path/to/file.scala`

or

`scala> :load http://path/to/file.scala`

Comment: That's a great use case.  I'll add it to my fix somewhere to -i, which breaks completion at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You could use instruments from your OS.

If you have `sh` and `wget`:

```
tmpfile=`mktemp` && \
wget https://gist.github.com/hanxue/8423482/raw/a525ae8a144d83195de72d402afb0fdc155cadf9/ConsoleColorise.scala -q -O $tmpfile && \
scala -i $tmpfile && \
rm $tmpfile
```

Comment: Ha. I have to say more than "ha" to register a comment, so I'll add that although we tend to assume nowadays that all resources are internetworked, there's still a place for abstracting layers.